# AJAX - looped variables, only first result being passed

Tags: sql, ajax, loops

I loop data from a SQL query and put it all into a form. Three variables are being retrieved from SQL for each data set: `BetID` and `BetHome` and `BetAway`.

Now I'd like to alter the data within a form and pass it through ajax.

**Problem**: only the first data set is being altered, all others remain untouched.

Any idea what is wrong with my JavaScript code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#betting").click(function(){

                var val1 = $("#BetID").val();
                var val2 = $("#BetHome").val();
                var val3 = $("#BetAway").val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "betting-ajax.php",
                    data: { BetID: val1, BetHome: val2, BetAway: val3 },
                    success: function(html){
                        $("#hide").hide();
                        $("#new").html(html);
                    }
                });
                return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

PHP is basically this structure:

```
<form id="betting">
MY SQL query starting here {
<select id="BetHome"><option value="1">1</option></select>
<select id="BetAway"><option value="1">1</option></select>
<input type="hidden" name="BetID" id="BetID" value="<?php echo $BetID ?>"

<button type="submit" name="submit">Save</button>

<?php } ?>
</form>
```

As said with this form (query inside the form) and above explained javascript code, only the first data set gets altered, all followed data set not changing.

Comment: Can you share your from with the code how do you loop through the sql data set

Comment: Put the form online. See above

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
          var val1 = $("#BetID").val();
          var val2 = $("#BetHome").val();
          var val3 = $("#BetAway").val();

          $("#BetHome").on("change", function(){
               val1 = $(this).val();
          });

          $("#BetAway").on("change", function(){
               val1 = $(this).val();
          })
        $("#betting").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "betting-ajax.php",
                    data: { BetID: val1, BetHome: val2, BetAway: val3 },
                    success: function(html){
                        $("#hide").hide();
                        $("#new").html(html);
                    }
                });
                return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

The reason is you need to get the new value of the changed drop down.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand what you are asking but whenever you dump html into the dom you need to rebind your events if the new html is replacing stuff that has events hooked to it.

So after this:

```
$("#new").html(html);
```

You need to bind the click event again:

```
$("#betting").click(function()...
```